# XSLT - If condition inside for-each definition

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to add a condition to a for-each loop such that if an attribute value matches a predefined variable, then select entries where the condition is met, else match all entries.

For example, I have 2 input XML like below:

```
<root>
 <a value="z">
  <b value="y">
   <c value="x">
    <var1>someData</var1>
    <var2>someOtherData</var2>
   </c>
   <c value="x2">
    <var1>someData</var1>
    <var2>someOtherData</var2>
   </c>
  </b>
 </a>
 <a value="w">
  <b value="v">
   <c value="u">
    <var1>someData2</var1>
    <var2>someOtherData2</var2>
   </c>
   <c value="u2">
    <var1>someData2</var1>
    <var2>someOtherData2</var2>
   </c>
  </b>
 </a>
</root>
```

each element besides `<root>` can repeat n times, identifiable by the attribute value.

And a second input xml like:

```
<filter>
 <aValue>z</aValue>
 <bValue>y</bValue>
 <cValue></cValue>
</filter>
```

I can use a for-each loop to iterate through the elements, e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/a" >
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or selectively by defining the attribute value:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/a[@value='z']" >
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

The 2nd input XML does not always contain a filter value for every element.
In case this element doesnt contain a value, I need to match all elements.
Is there a cleaner solution than nesting each element filter inside `<xsl:if>` statements?

I can use xslt 1.0 or 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the variable `$required` to the required value if supplied, or to "*" otherwise, then you can use the predicate

```
[@value = $required or $required = "*"]
```

In 2.0 you could write this as `[(@value, "*") = $required]`.

You can of course use some value other than "*" to indicate that "anything goes". For example "". Or in 2.0, it would be natural to use the empty sequence, in which case the predicate condition becomes simply `[@value = $required]`, because this will always be false if `$required` is empty.